# Save TFS build pipeline into the version control

Tags: tfs, version-control, build, continuous-integration, pipeline

I'm recently working with TFS 2015. I've realized that Microsoft has introduced a new way to configure TFS build pipelines which I think it is very intuitive.

Anyone knows if there is a mechanism to export or save these build configuration?

I think that it would be very useful to have the configuration into the versión control.

Thus, a user could review the history about how the pipeline has been changed. Also it would be possible to clone the build pipeline into another TFS continuous integration server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into source control? No. But go look at the "History" view on any build definition, it will show you exactly what you want: A full revision history of the build definition.